# how can install analysis-morphology plugin

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin

I trying to install elasticsearch plugin in dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.4.1
```

RUN bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://gitflic.ru/project/l2u-mirror/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology

and have an error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Plugin [.installing-15765791309144904613] is missing a descriptor properties file

How I can install analysis-morphology plugin for elasticsearch?